# "Unexpected end of JSON input" when parsing JSON from another file in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access a local JSON file in my Chrome extension from the background script with an XMLHttpRequest.

background.js:

```
// Cross-browser support
window.browser = (() => {
  return window.msBrowser || window.chrome || window.browser;
})();

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  var response = xhr.responseText;
  debugger; // typeof response === "string"

  response = JSON.parse(response); // Line 12 from error message
  debugger; // typeof response === "object"
}
xhr.open('GET', browser.runtime.getURL('option_defaults.json'), true); // Line 15 from error message
xhr.send();
```

option_defaults.json:

```
{
  "foo": "false"
}
```

Whenever this code is run and the `response` variable is parsed with `JSON.parse()`, it becomes a JSON object like it should. However, Chrome also gives this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (background.js:12)
    at background.js:15
```

I've read other similar questions that said to make sure the JSON is valid, which it is, and it returns the value as an object like I want it to, but it still gives an error despite everything seeming to work correctly. Why am I getting this error?

Edit:

This is what the network inspector shows:

[image: The results returned by the Chrome network inspector]

Comment: What does Chrome say the network request responds is in the network inspector?

Comment: And consider using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) if you can.

Comment: And another comment: `"foo": "false"` should be `"foo": false` FYI but I assume you're just testing thing here

Comment: @Dominik It gives a 200 status code for options_defaults.json via xhr. As far as the JSON goes, I actually thought both the property name and value always had to have quotes in JSON files even if it's a boolean value, so thanks for that. It also does the same thing without quotes.

Comment: Means you do not have JSON

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of you network inspector with the responds?

Comment: @epascarello [`200` means OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success) and can very well mean there is a JSON return... I just want to know exactly what is being returned. Not the header but the body

Comment: So 200 means it got the file.... does not mean anything about the contents. When parse fails, it throws an error. What is exactly in the response? OP needs to log it out.

Comment: Indeed. Exactly what I said :)

Comment: @Dominik I added a picture of the network inspector results.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like you're not calling an API but a json file directly? I never tried that before.

Comment: @Dominik Yes. I was going to use the file to store default options on `browser.runtime.onInstalled`. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but I couldn't find anything better from web searches.

Comment: Maybe use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? I feel like Chrome may have security concerns about requesting json files directly.

Comment: @Dominik I planned to use localStorage but I wanted to store some default values first when the browser was installed without hardcoding the values into JavaScript. I wasn't going to actually store the new values in a JSON file.

Comment: You aren't waiting for `xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE`. You should also check that `xhr.status === 200`. As @Dominik mentioned, use `fetch()` since it is able to abstract away these low-level details

Comment: @Phil Thanks for that. It works now.

Comment: Or just use `xhr.onload` event...